# Remove point at the end of book references, but keep italic style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing, declare

I want to have a combination of those two things. First one:
[image]

and second:

[image]

You see, they are quite similar, it's just the title of the book. I know how to lose the point at the end, but then the title isn't any more italic. I want to have it italic without a point at the end. Does anybody know how to solve this? The following code produces the first picture, however I commented the command for the second picture out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{mhra2013,
        Address = {London},
        Author = {{Modern Humanities Research Association}},
        Publisher = {Modern Humanities Research Association},
        Title = {{MHRA} style guide: A handbook for authors and editors},
        Year = {2013},
    }
\end{filecontents}

%\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1\nopunct     %%%% is that the key?

\begin{document}
    TEST: \cite{mhra2013} 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I would be so happy for help!

Comment: `\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\textit{#1}\nopunct}`?

Comment: oh...that was easy :D Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\textit{#1}\nopunct}
```

Huge thanks to @hair-splitter!